# Vscode says the class does not exist in the library module but builds properly. How can I fix this?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a module with a class that I exported. I have exported that class in **public-api.ts**. My consuming application says that class is not found in my library module. Everything seems to work properly. How can I fix my vscode to show that the class is there?

```
// public-api.ts
export * from './lib/shared/my-class';

// Consuming application's component
import { MyClass } from 'my-library';
```

Comment: how you have installed `my-library`? Also how you have built the library?

Comment: I used npm to install the library locally on the consuming app. Both projects built properly

Comment: how the library is built? have you used `ngx-packagr`?

Comment: I just click 'build' under NPM SCRIPTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably VS code has no idea of types in the library hence there might be error.

Please check if you have `declaration: true` in you library `tsconfig.json` file. 
This will create types files along with your build code e.g. `.d.ts`

Build you library again with mentioned configuration, and install it once again;

`.d.ts` files are used by the VS code and typescript compiler to check type safety and provide you with intellisense.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "declaration": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As there is possibility that VS code have not loaded types, restarting the VS code might help.

Comment: Inside my consuming app node_module/my-library/my-library.d.ts, I see that its exporting * from './public-api'

Comment: When I do import { MyClass } from 'My-Library/shared/my-class', vscode doesn't complain but when I build it it fails.

Comment: I think restarting vscode worked. I no longer see vscode errors. I should have done that in the first place xD